# Vertical position not respecting overflowing

Tags: html, css

A inner div may bigger than the outer div. The elements after the outer div belongs to the size of the outer div only.

```css
.ov{
  overflow:visible;
}
.h100{
  height:100px;
}
.h200{
  height:200px;
}
.green{
  border-color:green;
}
.red{
  border-color:red;
}
.blue{
  border-color:blue;
}
div{
  border:3px solid black;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="green h100 ov">
  <div class="red h200">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blue">
    I am right under green, but i like to be right under red!
</div>
```

How to respect the overflowing size in positioning the elements after the shrinking div?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Explicitly setting height is trouble in general.

Comment: @sheriffderek why is it "trouble in general"?

Comment: You cant always know what will be in each box. What if the text is longer? What if the image is bigger? what if the font size gets larger? If you are doing some very specific visual design where you know your content and it's constraints are set, then it's ok.

Comment: You may want to read about 'clear-fix' and clearing floats too - as this is something you'll have to deal with in that world.

Comment: The box is right where it is supposed to be. Imagine the red box lives inside of the green box and then you turn that box -145deg... that's where the box position is... in that corner... and then you told the boxes how tall to be... but but blue box is still after the green box...  because that's where it lives according to the defaults from what your markup says.

Comment: @sheriffderek float should not be concerned in this. What do you not understand? The height of the box is the height without the rotation afaik.

Comment: You set the explicit height of the green box. So it has that height. The red box lives on another plane now because CSS is weird. Try taking off the heights and see what happens. Good luck! : ) Look into relative and static and absolute positioning.

Comment: If i drop the specific height the inner red div is not overflowing anymore. But this question **explicitly** concerns the overflowing. See, I need to add a margin-top of 100px to the blue-div, only this way i make the blue-div is right under the red-div. But i do not like to specify a margin-top to the blue-div!

Comment: If you explain your larger intent, I could show you the correct way to make it, but otherwise - this just seems like growing pains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite straightforward. We can just use a float and clear pair to move the blue box down. We put a floated pseudo element below the `.red` div and inside the `.green` div with

```
.green:after {
  content:'';
  float:left;
}
```

Then the blue box just needs to clear that to be below it.

```
.blue {
  clear:left;
}
```

```css
.ov{
  overflow:visible;
}
.h100{
  height:100px;
}
.h200{
  height:200px;
}
.green{
  border-color:green;
}
.red{
  border-color:red;
}
.blue{
  border-color:blue;
}
div{
  border:3px solid black;
  margin:10px;
}
.green:after {
  content:'';
  float:left;
}
.blue {
  clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="green h100 ov">
  <div class="red h200">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blue">
    I am under green, but now right under red too!
</div>
```

Comment: But i do not understand it. The `.green:after` is on the same node-deepness as `div.green` and `div.blue` are! So `.green:after` means after the `.green` and that is directly under the green div. But effective `.green:after` is directly under the red div. I am confused.

Comment: `.green:after` means after the `.green` div's *content*. That is, it is inside the `.green` div, and therefore a following sibling of the `.red` div.

Answer (score 1):

Change `height` to `min-height`:

```css
.ov{
  overflow:visible;
}
.h100{
  min-height:100px;
}
.h200{
  min-height:200px;
}
.green{
  border-color:green;
}
.red{
  border-color:red;
}
.blue{
  border-color:blue;
}
div{
  border:3px solid black;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="green h100 ov">
  <div class="red h200">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blue">
    I am right under green, but i like to be right under red!
</div>
```

**ADDED**

Of course, you can do so:

```css
.ov{
  overflow:visible;
}
.h100{
  height:100px;
}
.h200{
  height:200px;
}
.green{
  border-color:green;
}
.red{
  border-color:red;
}
.blue{
  border-color:blue;
}
div{
  border:3px solid black;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="green h100 ov">
  <div class="red h200">
  </div>
  <div class="blue">
    I am right under green, but i like to be right under red!
  </div>
</div>
```

But you will understand where is the real borders of green block, if you will add `style="overflow: hidden"` to it:

```css
.ov{
  overflow:visible;
}
.h100{
  height:100px;
}
.h200{
  height:200px;
}
.green{
  border-color:green;
}
.red{
  border-color:red;
}
.blue{
  border-color:blue;
}
div{
  border:3px solid black;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="green h100 ov" style="overflow: hidden">
  <div class="red h200">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blue">
    I am right under green, but i like to be right under red!
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see what is unique here, compared to the OP's code.

Comment: Please run the code snippet, the blue box is right under green, but it likes to be right under red!

Comment: But why? I keep comparing the 2 sets of code. What is the difference?

Comment: Usually in an answer, you explain the answer.

Comment: I changed `height` to `min-height` =)

Comment: Sorry, I really forgot to add comment.

Comment: Well, while that works - it's not really what will answer the real question which is "why does this weird thing happen" - and the real answer is that the basic understanding of the CSS box-model isn't there. Interesting that the min height triggers some layout change though.

Comment: @LeonidZakharov I use chrome and the blue box is still right under the green box, but the blue box likes to be right under the red box.

Comment: `height: 100px` = height will be exactly 100px. If some inner element will have 200px, it will be painted as 200px element, but in this case next element `<div class="blue">` goes after `<div class="green h100 ov">` that has 100px height. So, it drawed exactly after this element that has `100px` height. And it doesn't matter that some internal elements has much more heights. When i changed css instructions from `height` to `min-height` I sad to browser that if some internal elements will have bigger height and parent element need to be resized - ok, but never do height less than 100px

Comment: @PeterRader, of course! If you want that blue box goes after red box, you need to move blue box after red box in the code. But in this case blue box goes after the green box.

Comment: @LeonidZakharov You telling me, its not possible? OK,but let me please wait for other answers.